# sql-alchemy open session from an active session

Tags: python, python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm new to sql-alchemy and trying to understand what will happen in the following case:

let's assume that I have the following code:

```
with db.mysession() as session:
     first_obj = session.query(db.my_table).filter(db.obj.index == 1)
     second_obj = session.query(db.my_table).filter(db.obj.index == 2)
     first_obj.delete()
     # note this was not commited to the db and I'm creating a new session
     session = db.mysession()
     second_obj_2 = session.query(db.my_table).filter(db.obj.index == 2)
     second_obj_2 = "some_change"
```

mysession() just opens and sqlalchemy session to the db and closes it on exit.

- the question is what will happen? does the deleted object is actually deleted? or it wasn't because the session was overridden?
- is there any difference between the two sessions? which changes will I see at the end of this code?
- I didn't close the inner session on purpose, what happens to unclosed sessions?

Comment: The context handling still sees the original session, so it depends on what does your context handler do.

Comment: what will the default context handler do in this case?

Comment: The question is: what is `mysession`?

Comment: no, the question is the following: at the end of this piece of code, which changes are saved to the db, and which are not? and why?

Comment: And to answer that, you must provide what `mysession` is and does. (Was confused 'bout the `delete()` call but noticed that you're using just query objects).

Comment: Also `second_obj_2 = "some_change"` is just an assignment to the name second_obj_2 that was bound to the `Query` object before. Now whether or not the delete takes place depends on a lot of things you've not included here. For example autocommit settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some investigation, here is what happened:

we were opening the session context without closing it, causing the session._depth to become unbalanced so the outer context couldn't commit and therefore all of the changes were not committed.